# Stuck exposing a port of Docker

Tags: docker

I'm stuck on port mapping in Docker.

I want to map port 8090 on the outside of a container to port 80 on the inside of the container.

Here is the container running:

```
ea41c430105d        tag-xx   "/usr/local/openrest…"   4 minutes ago     Up 4 minutes          8090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8090->80/tcp     web
```

Notice that it says that port 8090 is mapped to port 80.

Now inside another container I do

```
curl web
```

I get a `401` response. Which means that the container responds. So far so good.

But when I do `curl web:8090` I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to web port 8090: Connection refused
```

Why is port mapping not working for me?

Thanks

P.S. I know that specifically my container responds to `curl web` with a 401 because when I stop `docker stop web` and do `curl web` again, I get `could not resolve host: web`.

Comment: How you start the 2 containers? And what port is really open in `web container`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to a published port from inside another container because those are only available on the host. In your case:

From host:

- `curl localhost:8090` will connect to your container
- `curl localhost:80` won't connect to your container because the port isn't published

From another container in the same network

- `curl web` will work
- `curl web:8090` won't work because the only port exposed and listening for the web service is the 80.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers unless specified connects to the **default bridge** network. This default bridge network does not support automatic DNS resolution between containers. It looks like you are most likely on the default bridge network. However, on a default bridge network, you could connect using the container IP Address which can be found out using the following command

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container name>
```

So, `curl <IP Address of web container>:8090` should work.

It is always better to create a **user defined bridge network** and attach the containers to this network. On a user defined bridge network, the containers that are connected have their ports exposed to each other and not to the outside world. The user defined bridge network also support automatic DNS resolution and you could refer to the container's name instead of IP Address. You could try the following commands to create a user defined bridge network and attach your containers to it.

```
docker network create --driver bridge my-net
docker attach web
docker attach <other container name>
```

Now, from the other container you should be able to run curl on the 'web' container.

Answer (score 0):

You can create network to connect between containers.
Or you can use --link :

> docker run --name container1 -p 80:???? -d image (expose on port 80)
>
> docker run --name container2 --links lcontainer1:container1

and inside container2 you can use :

> curl lcontainer1

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**look this port is mostly used by docker-proxy**

To enhance your understanding, follow these steps for additional knowledge.

First, check if the port is already in use by using one of these commands.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

If you encounter something like this:

```
tcp 0  0 0.0.0.0:8090  ...
```

If the port is already in use, you can run this command to identify the process using it.

```
sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :8090'
```

Check your results to identify who is using the port.

```
State    Recv-Q   Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port Process
LISTEN   0  4096   0.0.0.0:8090  0.0.0.0:*  users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1175,fd=4))
```